# Expression.Error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized. Make sure it's spelled correctly

Tags: dynamic, microsoft-dynamics, powerbi

I am trying to use `if else` query in PowerBI

Below is my query

```
=IF(([Status]=100000004),"hello","world")
```

But this is not working

It says

> Expression.Error: The name 'IF' wasn't recognized.  Make sure it's
>   spelled correctly.

What I want to achieve is,

```
IF([status]=11,"Open")
else if([status]=12,"Close")
else ("reject")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The power query syntax is as below

```
if([Status]=100000004) then "Open" else "Close"
```

Once you do this you and click ok, you will be able to see the below query editor

[image]

You can just click on add rule and keep adding more If else etc